# How to clean a new remote git repository?

Tags: git, latex

Well, maybe someone asked this before, excuse me if I ask it again.

I was working my thesis for a long time stored in a directory within Dropbox.

Now for the revisions I'm receiving helping from some people, and since all this was generated in LaTeX, a repository in git is a good idea. I have to confess that I'm quite new using it.

So I opened an account inside Bitbucket for store a remote repository from my project (thesis) and ease the revisions and other changes.

I tried to follow the instructions for create the repository, but I make a mistake, the step I followed were:

```
$ echo "Aradenatorix Veckhom Vacelaevus" >> contributors.txt
$ git add contributors.txt
$ git commit -m 'Initial commit with contributors'
$ git push -u origin master
```

I did the first 3 lines, but then I saw it was unnecesary becase they was the instructions for create my first file, commit and push, but I have yet a lot of files from the project. The right steps are:

```
cd /path/to/my/repo
git remote add origin https://Aradenatorix@bitbucket.org/Aradenatorix/tesis.git
git push -u origin --all # 
git push -u origin --tags #
```

The firs one I did before so I have no troubles with that, instead of follow the 4th step from the wrong instructions before, I did the second one from this, but when I tried the third I had an error:

```
No refs in common and none specified; doing nothing.
Perhaps you should specify a branch such as 'master'.
```

However I don't need to add all the content of the directory, only the `.tex`files and a subdirectory with the attached pictures. After explaining the above I have two doubts:

1. I know that I can start git with `$ git init` but... How to stop it?
2. How to remove all those files bad loaded to that remote repository?

I tried with `$ git rm` and many options such as `--dry-run`, `--cached`, `-r` and `--ignore-unmatched` but nothing works yet.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Was your thesis previously under source control in a local git repo? If not, you first need to commit the files locally before you push them to the remote. If you run git status, you should see all the files in an unstated area. Add, and commit them first, and then try git push -u origin master

Comment: If you've already committed all the of the non .tex files, then you'll need to rm them, then git add --all ., and commit the removal of those files.

Comment: @SimplicityGuy Actually not, my thesis was not under another local git repo, this will be the first. How can I remove the unnecessary files from the local repo?

Comment: If you want to prevent files that you don't want to be checked in, create a .gitignore. But since you may have checked in the files that you don't want already, you'll need to manually delete them. Use rm -f name-of-file, then git add --all ., and then git commit.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you would have made just a couple of commits. You can recreate the commit.

```
git reset HEAD~<number of commits>
rm path/to/unnecessary/file
```

Add new files which were not previously added (optional):

```
git add new/files
git commit
```

To get the number of commits (which should probably be 1 or 2 in your case),

```
git rev-list HEAD --count
```

Finally, do a force push.

```
git push origin master --force
```

This option should be used only if your repo is not shared with other people and you know what you are doing. You will overwrite the remote. All you remote changes will be overwritten by the local changes.

As you mentioned, it is a fresh repository and you haven't used version control for your project before. So I think you can go ahead with it.